# reverse entries in (multi-dimensional) array in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, openstreetmap, reverse, leaflet

I'm using leafletjs to display some polygons on an openstretmap.

I have an external data ressource which gives me the coordinates for the polygons. Unfortunately this array has the wrong order for the coordinates.

Example:
I get:

> [[10.5254913,52.2734311],[10.5258872,52.2734632]]

I need:

> [[52.2734311,10.5254913],[52.2734632,10.5258872]]

So I wrote myself a little function which iterates through the array and reverses the entries:

```
var polCoords = [];
$.each(value.polygon[0], function(key,value){
polCoords[key] = [value[1],value[0]]; 
});
```

This works just fine. But now I discovered that some arrays for the polygons are multidimensional! So I have an array like this:

```
[[[10.5261828,52.2726556],[10.5263222,52.2726767],[10.5263578,52.2726821],[10.5263637,52.2726677],[10.5263738,52.2726428],[10.5264042,52.2725678],[10.526186,52.2725346],[10.5261395,52.272649],[10.5261828,52.2726556]],[[10.5261828,52.2726556],[10.5261713,52.2726821],[10.5261621,52.2727047],[10.5259248,52.2726687],[10.5257879,52.2726479],[10.5257435,52.2727573],[10.5258014,52.2727661],[10.5257967,52.2727777],[10.5260173,52.2728113],[10.5261107,52.2728254],[10.5260641,52.2729403],[10.5259711,52.2729262],[10.5259526,52.2729234],[10.5258101,52.2732746],[10.5258697,52.2732837],[10.5260636,52.2733132],[10.5261371,52.2733243],[10.5262746,52.2729854],[10.5262888,52.2729876],[10.526312,52.2729304],[10.5262636,52.2729231],[10.5262239,52.272917],[10.5263222,52.2726767],[10.5261828,52.2726556]],[[10.5260636,52.2733132],[10.5260595,52.2733365],[10.5260575,52.2733486],[10.5258607,52.2733326],[10.5258631,52.2733195],[10.5258697,52.2732837],[10.5260636,52.2733132]]]
```

Which seems to consist of more than one polygon.

How can I reverse every entry of this multidimensional array?

Answer (score 3):

```
array=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

reverse_2D_array=array.map(row=>row.reverse()).reverse()

reverse_2D_array=[[9,8,7],[6,5,4],[3,2,1]]
```

> Note: this method will change the original array.

Comment: thanks! This is one of the cleanest method

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `array` is your data, try something like:

```
var reversed = array.map(function reverse(item) {
    return Array.isArray(item) && Array.isArray(item[0]) 
               ? item.map(reverse) 
               : item.reverse();
});
```

This is vanilla JavaScript. I think in jquery would be something like:

```
var reversed = $.map(array, function reverse(item) {
    return $.isArray(item) && $.isArray(item[0])
               ? $.map(item, reverse)
               : item.reverse();
});
```

I didn't try but should works both of them. Let me know.

Comment: vanilla javaScript should work too. No need for jQuery.

I'm testing this, but I get 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: I found a solution for my problem, but it's not the answer for this question.
Just in case someone else runs into the same problem: I'm using geoJSON now in Leaflet, which accepts the gps coordinates in the way I receive them.

Comment: I didn't test the jQuery one, but the vanilla one, with the data you wrote, and it worked – also, there is no access to `length` there, so it can't be that code. Anyway, glad you solved in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //given array
        var arr = [
                    [
                        [10.5261828, 52.2726556],
                        [10.5263222, 52.2726767],
                        [10.5263578, 52.2726821],
                        [10.5263637, 52.2726677],
                        [10.5263738, 52.2726428],
                        [10.5264042, 52.2725678],
                        [10.526186, 52.2725346],
                        [10.5261395, 52.272649],
                        [10.5261828, 52.2726556]
                    ],
                    [
                        [10.5261828, 52.2726556],
                        [10.5261713, 52.2726821],
                        [10.5261621, 52.2727047],
                        [10.5259248, 52.2726687],
                        [10.5257879, 52.2726479],
                        [10.5257435, 52.2727573],
                        [10.5258014, 52.2727661],
                        [10.5257967, 52.2727777],
                        [10.5260173, 52.2728113],
                        [10.5261107, 52.2728254],
                        [10.5260641, 52.2729403],
                        [10.5259711, 52.2729262],
                        [10.5259526, 52.2729234],
                        [10.5258101, 52.2732746],
                        [10.5258697, 52.2732837],
                        [10.5260636, 52.2733132],
                        [10.5261371, 52.2733243],
                        [10.5262746, 52.2729854],
                        [10.5262888, 52.2729876],
                        [10.526312, 52.2729304],
                        [10.5262636, 52.2729231],
                        [10.5262239, 52.272917],
                        [10.5263222, 52.2726767],
                        [10.5261828, 52.2726556]
                    ],
                    [
                        [10.5260636, 52.2733132],
                        [10.5260595, 52.2733365],
                        [10.5260575, 52.2733486],
                        [10.5258607, 52.2733326],
                        [10.5258631, 52.2733195],
                        [10.5258697, 52.2732837],
                        [10.5260636, 52.2733132]
                    ]
                ];        

        var arrModified = new Array();
        var intDepth = 0;

        //array depth calculation
        function arrayDepth(arr) {
            for(item in arr) {
                if (Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) === '[object Array]') {
                    intDepth++;
                    arrayDepth(item);
                }
            }
        }
        arrayDepth(arr);

        //for depth 1
        if (intDepth == 1) {            
                arrModified = arr.reverse();
        }

        //for depth 2
        if (intDepth == 2) {
            for (item in arr) {
                arrModified[item] = arr[item].reverse();
            }
        }

        //for depth 3
        if (intDepth == 3) {
            for (i in arr) {
                var arrTemp = arr[i];
                var arrTemp1 = new Array();
                for (j in arrTemp) {
                    arrTemp1[j] = arrTemp[j].reverse();
                }
                arrModified[i] = arrTemp1;                
            }            
        }

        //so on for other depths
        //arrModified is the required array

    </script>
```

Comment: Hardcoded depths levels? Why not use recursive function?